# Create a VIEW that displays the titles

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to Create a VIEW

This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT Book.BookTitle
FROM Book, Borrower, Client
WHERE Book.BookId = Borrower.BookId AND Borrower.ClientId = Client.ClientId AND COUNT(Book.BookId) > 
(SELECT COUNT(Client.ClientId) FROM Client)*0.2
GROUP BY Book.BookTitle
ORDER BY COUNT(Book.BookTitle) DESC;
```

I keep getting this error: 
Msg 147, Level 15, State 1, Line 547
An aggregate may not appear in the WHERE clause unless it is in a subquery contained in a HAVING clause or a select list, and the column being aggregated is an outer reference.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I see multiple tables in the `FROM` clause but no `JOIN`.  Why not?

Comment: @GordonLinoff old-school way of "joining":)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this query is going to give you what you need i.e "*display the titles that were borrowed by at least 20% of clients*" but I corrected your query syntactically. You can not use aggregate functions in `where` clause. And `group by` clause is at incorrect position in your query.

```
SELECT 
Book.BookTitle, COUNT(Book.BookId)
FROM 
Book 
join Borrower
on Book.BookId = Borrower.BookId
join Client
on Borrower.ClientId = Client.ClientId 
GROUP BY Book.BookTitle
having COUNT(Book.BookId) > 
(SELECT COUNT(Client.ClientId) FROM Client)*0.2
ORDER BY COUNT(Book.BookTitle) DESC;
```